# Python get and post requests fails with Connection and GetAddrinfo

Tags: python, get, python-requests

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://http2bin.org/get')
```

I am getting below errors:

```
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
HTTPConnectionPool(host='http2bin.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded
with url: /get (Caused by
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
0x031CAB08>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004]
getaddrinfo failed'))
```

What could be the reason? Is it related to Proxy ?

Comment: Seems that your host ('http2bin.org') in not reachable.

Answer (score 1):

It's a website problem.Try it with another website surely it would work.